# PHP autoupdate form data without pageload

Tags: php, forms

I run a php script game site, and there's a section of it where a player can distribute his 'skill points' in 'Attack', 'Defence', or 'Stamina'.

At the moment, it's just a basic HTML/PHP form with a + next to each stat, so if the user had 100 points and wanted to put them all into ATTACK, he'd have to click (and pageload) 100 times. Obviously that's silly.

I want to be able to make it so the player can distribute them (without page reloads), then finally click SUBMIT once he's happy with it.

Could anyone point me in the direction of what I need to do this? Is it some ajax or javascript? I suppose I could do form fields and clicking the PLUS would increment each field..

Comment: Yeah you can just do this with javascript.  You've basically got it.  You use the onClick event in javascript to increment a variable, and then write the variable to a hidden form element.  You could use Ajax but if there's a final submit you'll save DB work by just doing it with javascript/form data.

Comment: Alright, well I'm useless at javascript but i'll see what I can find out.

Comment: I was too originally, (so was everyone) check out jQuery though.  There's some good tutorials online and it makes this kind of stuff REALLY easy :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need an `onclick()` to call a javascript function for the plus button, that increments the value in javascript, updates on the page and checks that the user has distributed the points correctly (i.e. distributed 100 points or under in your example) and then have another button at the bottom of your points distribution that sends the data to a PHP page that handles the storage of the values.

If you wanted you could then use ajax to send that data to the PHP page without having to reload the page. I've found the W3schools site adequate for teaching basic ajax usage: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

(But remember to check the user input on the server side as well, don't trust user input!)